# how to split /consider 3 character in each row

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have one doubt in sql server

how to split length of 3 upto last charcters in sql server

```
table : emp 
id  | name  
1   | harikrishnaxx
2   | Baludevu
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
id  | name 
1   | har
1   |ikr
1   |ish
1   |nax
1   |x
2   | bal
2   |ude
2   |vu
```

i tried like below : 
1st I create tablevalued funtion then called this function in emp table

```
create  FUNCTION DatesBetween(@name varchar(50))
RETURNS @dates TABLE (
   DateValue varchar(50)  NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN
declare @fin varchar(50)
declare @len int = (select len(@name))
declare @i int 
set @i=1
while (@i <=@len)
begin
insert into @dates (DateValue)values(@fin)
set  @fin =SUBSTRING (@name ,@i,3)
set @i=@i+3
   END;
 RETURN;
END;

select  id ,   dbo.DatesBetween(name ) from emp
```

but above query not getting exact result .
can you please tell me how to solve this issue in sql server

Answer (score 1):

Create this inline table-valued user-defined function that can adapt to whatever size you want your chunks to be:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ChunkNames(@name varchar(50), @len int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH n(n) AS 
    (
      SELECT n=1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT n+1 FROM n 
        WHERE n < LEN(@name)/@len
              + CASE LEN(@name)%@len WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 END
    )
    SELECT n, chunk = SUBSTRING(@name,(n-1)*@len+1,@len) FROM n
  );
GO
```

Now, with the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #emp
(id int, name sysname);

INSERT #emp(id,name) VALUES(1,'harikrishnaxx'),
  (2,'Baludevu'),(3,'woo'),(4,'booboo');
```

Then with this query:

```
SELECT e.id, name = f.chunk 
  FROM #emp AS e
  CROSS APPLY dbo.ChunkNames(e.name,3) AS f
  ORDER BY e.id, f.n;
```

You get the following results:

```
id  name
--  ----
1   har
1   ikr
1   ish
1   nax
1   x
2   Bal
2   ude
2   vu
3   woo
4   boo
4   boo
```

If you need to reuse this for other strings to break apart that might be longer than 100 characters, you'll have to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the query.